# Python crashes when I try to run code in Aquamacs

Tags: python, emacs, aquamacs

I'm fairly new to Aquamacs, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I haven't found any posts relevant to my problem so far.

I have a short python program that I want to run in Aquamacs. I opened the file in a new buffer and it recognized it as python, but when I went to run the program with C-c C-c, I get a popup saying "Python quit unexpectedly." I also get an error message in the buffer saying "Process python segmentation fault: 11"

This happens not just with the specific program I am trying to run, but any python script including "hello world" or when I try to open a python shell. I also dont know if this is relevant or not, but IDLE is working fine, its only when I try to run it from Aquamacs that there is a problem. I am using Python 2.7.

edit: These are the details in the error report

```
Process:               Python [6261]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.3 (2.7.3)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Aquamacs [552]
Responsible:           Aquamacs [552]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-18 09:35:04.934 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        7500208B-DB3F-AD6F-8037-873FE6C58A25

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B340FA74-DC61-4D3F-B609-579A11DF0943

Time Awake Since Boot: 4600 seconds
Time Since Wake:       470 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   readline.so                     0x00000001002eff97 call_readline + 647
1   org.python.python               0x0000000100008852 PyOS_Readline + 274
2   org.python.python               0x000000010000a0a8 tok_nextc + 104
3   org.python.python               0x000000010000a853 PyTokenizer_Get + 147
4   org.python.python               0x000000010000544a parsetok + 218
5   org.python.python               0x00000001000e7722 PyParser_ASTFromFile + 146
6   org.python.python               0x00000001000e8983 PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 243
7   org.python.python               0x00000001000e8c6e PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 78
8   org.python.python               0x00000001000e9451 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 161
9   org.python.python               0x000000010010006d Py_Main + 3085
10  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000100426770  rcx: 0x000000010023fa20  rdx: 0x000000010023fa00
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00000001002f0254  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff390  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff2c0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x0000000100400000  r11: 0x0000000000000001
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x000000000000009f  r14: 0x00007fff5fbff350  r15: 0x00007fff5fbff2d0
  rip: 0x00000001002eff97  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (2.7.3 - 2.7.3) <BE41DDF4-595E-0D6D-89DB-413749B339C3> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x100003000 -        0x10016dff7 +org.python.python (2.7.3, [c] 2004-2012 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.3) <4F9EF48A-7D0C-0C1A-670B-3BF4E72C8696> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1002ee000 -        0x1002f0fff +readline.so (???) <A33567B3-2793-9387-FD19-41FFD86C18E5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x1005b0000 -        0x1005cefff  libedit.2.dylib (40) <6049084C-478A-3A89-A9A1-E641B5F8C1A7> /usr/lib/libedit.2.dylib
    0x7fff65277000 -     0x7fff652ad837  dyld (353.2.1) <4696A982-1500-34EC-9777-1EF7A03E2659> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff82f7c000 -     0x7fff82fa7fff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff83566000 -     0x7fff8358efff  libsystem_info.dylib (459) <B85A85D5-8530-3A93-B0C3-4DEC41F79478> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff83780000 -     0x7fff8378bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) <D381EBC6-69D8-31D3-8084-5A80A32CB748> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff83abd000 -     0x7fff83ac1fff  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.1.4) <1DB04436-5974-3F16-86CC-5FF5F390339C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff84194000 -     0x7fff841aaff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff84520000 -     0x7fff84521fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff84526000 -     0x7fff84526ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff849e2000 -     0x7fff849e3fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff84a9f000 -     0x7fff84ad7ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (411) <C0B2313D-47BE-38A9-BEE6-2634A4F5E14B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff84ad8000 -     0x7fff84b00fff  libxpc.dylib (559.1.22) <9437C02E-A07B-38C8-91CB-299FAA63083D> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff86682000 -     0x7fff8669eff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff866fc000 -     0x7fff86704fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1) <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff867c9000 -     0x7fff867cbff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.1.1) <DB9962EF-8898-31CC-9B87-E01F8CE74C9D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff867e6000 -     0x7fff867ebff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff887be000 -     0x7fff889a3267  libobjc.A.dylib (646) <3B60CD90-74A2-3A5D-9686-B0772159792A> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff889a4000 -     0x7fff889a6ff7  libquarantine.dylib (76) <DC041627-2D92-361C-BABF-A869A5C72293> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff88b29000 -     0x7fff88b2afff  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <DA954461-EC6A-3DF0-8551-6FC810627627> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff88b2b000 -     0x7fff88b2eff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1) <19FAF435-C165-3374-9DEF-D7BBA7D61DB6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8a103000 -     0x7fff8a103ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8a11e000 -     0x7fff8a120ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff8ad10000 -     0x7fff8ad10ff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.1.22) <8A988924-8BE7-35FE-BF7D-322E90EFE49E> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8adf7000 -     0x7fff8ae3dff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8af22000 -     0x7fff8af52fff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8af53000 -     0x7fff8af5bfff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8c1bf000 -     0x7fff8c213fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8ca03000 -     0x7fff8ca0bffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8ca58000 -     0x7fff8cc3dff3  libicucore.A.dylib (531.30) <EF0E7544-E317-3550-A962-6AE65E78AF17> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8d49c000 -     0x7fff8d4ccff7  libncurses.5.4.dylib (44) <F09809A4-53B9-3E91-A8FA-D3F584C03AA3> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff8d6f9000 -     0x7fff8d6ffff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10) <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff8dbe9000 -     0x7fff8dc13ff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8dc14000 -     0x7fff8dc1dff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (133.1.1) <61147800-F320-3DAA-850C-BADF33855F29> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8deb4000 -     0x7fff8deb5ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8dfe9000 -     0x7fff8e075fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.1.2) <C185E862-7424-3210-B528-6B822577A4B8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8e091000 -     0x7fff8e097fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.1.3) <A9E6B7D8-C327-3742-AC54-86C94218B1DF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff8f4f0000 -     0x7fff8f50dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.1.97) <93E0E0A9-75B6-3904-BB4E-4BC7C05F4B6B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8f729000 -     0x7fff8f72affb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8f740000 -     0x7fff8f751ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8f783000 -     0x7fff8f78aff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8fa90000 -     0x7fff8fb06fe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) <E1789801-3985-3949-B736-6B3378873301> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8fb07000 -     0x7fff8fb18ff7  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.1.2) <EBBF7EF6-80D8-3F8F-825C-B412BD6D22C0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff90ce7000 -     0x7fff9107dfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1151.16) <F2B088AF-A5C6-3FAE-9EB4-7931AF6359E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff9110b000 -     0x7fff91114fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.1.4) <26B1897F-0CD3-30F3-B55A-37CB45062D73> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff917ab000 -     0x7fff917affff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff91aa4000 -     0x7fff91aa6fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <9FBA1CE4-97D0-347E-A443-93ED94512E92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff91c88000 -     0x7fff91c8dff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BE7E51A0-B6EA-3A54-9CCA-9D88F683A6D6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1833
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=83.8M resident=26.6M(32%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=57.2M(68%)
Writable regions: Total=28.3M written=2340K(8%) resident=2664K(9%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=25.7M(91%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             19.6M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        55.7M
Stack                              8516K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             1484K
__LINKEDIT                         70.8M
__TEXT                             13.0M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             169.4M

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0B, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533654465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK2555GSXF, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus:
```